# Where do divisors on curves come from?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, math-history, algebraic-curves

I've been learning about Riemann surfaces and the Riemann-Roch theorem, and I've been able to experience some of its great power. However, I'm curious as to what the history behind divisors on curves is, namely:

Why are they called divisors?

What inspired their creation? (Is there a motivating example?)

The formalism makes complete sense, and the results surely justify the theory, but how did anyone think, "Oh let's look at the free abelian group on the points of this surface and hope something good happens"? To me, they just seem like useful book-keeping objects to record local information about meromorphic functions, but is there some kind of geometric or intuitive way to think about these objects as more than just formalities that work?

Thank you

Comment: I suspect they are called "divisors" by analogy with the theory of number fields.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on that analogy? I'm not familiar with "divisors" in number fields.

Comment: The start of Section II.6 in Hartshorne has some good informal spiel about why we care about divisors. The moral is that (linear equivalence classes of) divisors are absolutely _not_ "just formalities that work": they are intimately connected to the possible maps from a curve to other projective varieties.

Comment: Is there a simpler way to explain the general idea? Hartshorne is a bit over my head at this point.

Comment: Some of the history and relations to the concept of divisors in number theory is given in the great answer to this mathoverflow question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/74427/does-the-name-divisor-in-algebraic-geometry-relate-to-divisor-in-the-basic-arith